Citrus tree with dried branches and falling leaves
I was told by someone at Home Depot it was root rot but I wanted a second opinion.
The main symptoms are sections with

no leaves
dead branches
Leaves with soot like substance heard it was harmless
Leaves with spots possibly harmful

The trunk looks fine and the ground around the tree look ok but I don’t really know much.
Heres are some pictures

Here’s a dried section. Dead branches and no leaves.

Here’s the trunk

A leaf with a possible disease, I’m not sure.

The area around the tree

Some dead dried up oranges
I hope that is enough info if you need more pictures of a specific section just say so.
11/18/2024
Update some close ups

Here there I show the many branches that are just dry. Is this an indication of not enough water?

Here are some fruit that are drying up. Again not enough water? I water for from sprinklers every other day for about 10 minutes. I'm adding drip watering from a hose.

Here is another dry branch

Here I broke the branch to see the inside.

Here is a trunk with many scratches on it. Don't know if that's harmful to the tree.

More dry branches

Some spots on the branches. Are these harmful to the tree?

There are many dried fruit. It was said in the comments that they are rotten. What could cause this?

From the picture it is difficult to see which branches dry. Could you add details: from bottom up (maybe just one large branch?) Or mostly the tip of branches? Or a mix, but you have some green shots in the middle? -- Try also to touch and check the trunk and main branches.

@giacomo Certainly I’ll get more pictures. I’ll get one to address each point

@GiacomoCatenazzi I added some close ups of the ends of the branches. Some dried, some with mold, and one of the trunk.
The trunk seems pretty good except for that scarring that I posted.
I missed getting some shots in the middle thankfully the middle seems ok. But I’ll double check and get some pics of the middle.

If you need more shots than just say so.

Too many pictures ;-) (could you add "figure X (below)" every few pictures? When the tree started to show symptoms? How it was previous years? -- I'm not a citrus expert, but to me it doesn't seem root problem. Most fruits seems OKish (possibly dry), but the last one is rot. A frost which damages some branches? Or very humid climate which damaged tissues? (or just softened and so insects or rot entered the branches?)

@GiacomoCatenazzi Better too many than too few right :P I would say the tree has always been like this since I moved in about 2 years ago. I live in Southern California so the cold does not get extreme. It doesn't get very humid either. I will add comments on each picture. Sorry about that. I'd like to ask more about the last picture. The fruit that's dried up. You believe it to be rotten? I haven't cut one open but I'll be sure to tonight. Is this normal to have fruit dry up and rot on the branch?
